# How to get a Scala Kafka Consumer in a Play application to continously listen to the broker through the life of the application?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, playframework, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a Play-Scala application that uses a Scala Kafka Consumer to listen to a Kafka broker. I am using the Cake Solutions [Scala Kafka Client](https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client) library, and following their example [here](https://medium.com/@dhpiggott/getting-started-with-kafka-using-scala-kafka-client-and-akka-f060624377a).

I have created a containing class to act as a Kafka consumer provider, and I have bound this as an eager singleton so that it is created when the application starts up.

The problem is that the consumer will listen to the broker when the application starts up, but not after that.

Here is my code for the ConsumerProvider:

```
trait KafkaConsumerProvider {

  def consumer: ActorRef

}

@Singleton
class KafkaConsumerProviderImpl @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, configuration: Configuration)
    extends KafkaConsumerProvider {

  private val consumerConf: KafkaConsumer.Conf[String, String] = KafkaConsumer.Conf(
    keyDeserializer = new StringDeserializer,
    valueDeserializer = new StringDeserializer,
    bootstrapServers = configuration.get[String]("messageBroker.bootstrapServers"),
    groupId = configuration.get[String]("messageBroker.consumer.groupId"),
    enableAutoCommit = false,
    autoCommitInterval= 1000,
    sessionTimeoutMs = 10000,
    maxPartitionFetchBytes = ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES,
    maxPollRecords = 500,
    maxPollInterval = 300000,
    maxMetaDataAge  = 300000,
    autoOffsetReset = OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST,
    isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.READ_UNCOMMITTED,
  )

  private val actorConf: KafkaConsumerActor.Conf = KafkaConsumerActor.Conf(
    scheduleInterval = 1.seconds,   // scheduling interval for Kafka polling when consumer is inactive
    unconfirmedTimeout = 3.seconds, // duration for how long to wait for a confirmation before redelivery
    maxRedeliveries = 3             // maximum number of times a unconfirmed message will be redelivered
  )

  override val consumer: ActorRef = {
    val receiverActor = actorSystem.actorOf(ReceiverActor.props)
    val topics = configuration.get[String]("messageBroker.consumer.topics").split(",").toSeq
    val _consumer = actorSystem.actorOf(KafkaConsumerActor.props(consumerConf, actorConf, receiverActor))
    _consumer ! Subscribe.AutoPartition(topics)
    _consumer
  }

}
```

and here is how I am binding the dependency as an eager singleton in `Module.scala`:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind[KafkaMessageBrokerWriter].to[KafkaMessageBrokerWriterImpl].asEagerSingleton()
    bind[KafkaConsumerProvider].to[KafkaConsumerProviderImpl].asEagerSingleton()
  }

}
```

How do I get the consumer to keep listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that, in the `ReceiverActor`, I forgot to confirm the offsets:

```
sender() ! Confirm(records.offsets)
```

Comment: @Capacytron: Yes it did work, I'll add code for the receiver actor.

Comment: @Capacytron: You would just add the code above into the body of the one of the partial function cases of the `receive` method in the `ReceiverActor`. The code for the receiver actor is not given above in the question, but is in the link cited in the above question: https://medium.com/@dhpiggott/getting-started-with-kafka-using-scala-kafka-client-and-akka-f060624377a